# Multiple File Selection Dialog

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, uploadify

I have a rails/jquery uploader I am working on and I want to offer users the ability to select multiple files from the dialog. However I can't seem to find much on actually making that happen. So I am hoping maybe I can find a little insight here. How do I trigger a browser dialog to allow multiple file selection, and when multiple file selection is complete and the user clicks "ok" how would I work with that? Does anyone know a good doc or 2? Does anyone know of any existing scripts that do this that maybe I can work with those instead. Im looking for something plain looking in general, but all in all I want to know how to get that dialog for file selection to work the way I'd like it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what you're looking for: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: That sir is perfect. Should hopefully save me so much time as well, won't have to reinvent the wheel to get things done. Thank you.